# Can you have a variable as a block definition name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, web-application-firewall

I'm trying to add an AWS WAF rule that grabs the values from variables and adds it as a block definition into the resource. I'm not sure if what I'm trying is possible or not, I'm getting the error:

> An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.

I'm guessing it's because it's seeing the variable in quotes and expecting ito to have an argument.

The block in question below is the "field_to_match" block.

Is there any way this can be done or an alternative option?

```html
resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl" "static_hosting" {
  provider    = aws.acm_us_region

  name        = "${var.cityName}-static-hosting"
  description = "WAF for ${var.cityName}-static-hosting"
  scope       = "CLOUDFRONT"

  default_action {
    block {}
  }

  rule {
    name     = "Check_Domain"
    priority = 1

    action {
      allow {}
    }

    statement {
      byte_match_statement {
        text_transformation {
            priority = 0
            type = "NONE"
        }
        field_to_match {
            var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.type {
                name = var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.name
            }

        }
        positional_constraint = var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.conditional
        search_string = var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.string
      }
    }
}
```

```html
"conditionalType": {
                "type": "single_header",
                "name": "referrer",
                "conditional": "CONTAINS",
                "string": "domain.com"
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments and blocks within a resource configuration cannot be dynamic in this way in Terraform, because they are checked statically at validation time rather than dynamically during plan/apply.

It seems like your goal here is to dynamically choose which of the several different possible block types to use inside `byte_match_statement`, based on the value of `var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.type`. Due to the design of this resource type this isn't a straightforward thing to write, but it *is* possible to achieve it by using a few different kinds of expression along with some [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html).

I'd start here by first producing some values that more directly match the expectations of `dynamic` blocks, where we have a collection to iterate over per block rather than a single name lookup. For example:

```
locals {
  query_type = var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.type

  all_query_arguments = local.query_type == "all_query_arguments" ? {} : null
  body                = local.query_type == "body" ? {} : null
  method              = local.query_type == "method" ? {} : null
  query_string        = local.query_type == "query_string" ? {} : null
  uri_path            = local.query_type == "uri_path" ? {} : null

  single_header = local.query_type == "single_header" ? {
    name = var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.name
  } : null

  single_query_argument = local.query_type == "single_query_argument" ? {
    name = var.serviceConfig.static_hosting.conditionalType.name
  } : null
}
```

What we've achieved here is having a separate symbol for each of the possible query types where at any time only one of them will be set and the others will all be `null`. This isn't *quite* what a `dynamic` block expects, but we can easily adapt from a value that might be null into a list with either zero or one elements using [the splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html), `[*]`. For example, `local.body[*]` would either be an empty list or a list containing a single element, depending on whether `local.body` is `null`.

This then gives us the inputs we need to write `dynamic` blocks that will produce either zero or one of each of the allowed block types, which means that in practice there will only be one total because we've arranged above that only one of them can be non-`null` at a time.

```
  field_to_match {
    dynamic "all_query_arguments" {
      for_each = local.all_query_arguments[*]
      content {}
    }
    dynamic "body" {
      for_each = local.body[*]
      content {}
    }
    dynamic "method" {
      for_each = local.method[*]
      content {}
    }
    dynamic "query_string" {
      for_each = local.query_string[*]
      content {}
    }
    dynamic "uri_path" {
      for_each = local.uri_path[*]
      content {}
    }
    dynamic "single_header" {
      for_each = local.uri_single_header[*]
      content {
        name = single_header.value.name
      }
    }
    dynamic "single_query_argument" {
      for_each = local.single_query_argument[*]
      content {
        name = single_query_argument.value.name
      }
    }
  }
```

This design of having a variety of different block types from which you can pick any one to set a value is a somewhat unusual design for a Terraform resource type, and so unfortunately making use of it *dynamically* like this is rather involved compared to the equivalent static configuration, but it should still be possible to make it dynamic with a strategy like this, albeit rather verbosely in order to allow Terraform to see that all of the possible outcomes will conform to the resource type's declared schema.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response @MartinAtkins. It makes sense. I've tried testing it however, and it's showing an error: 

The "each" object can be used only in "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set.

I'm a little confused as we've already set the for_each in the dynamic block. We are still on an older version of terraform right now, 12.7, I'm not sure if this has any bearing on it. I'll continue to try and debug the issue.

Comment: Sorry about that... I made an error when I was writing this. I tend to answer a bunch of questions all in one session so sometimes things in my brain from one answer can sneak into another. Notice that I've replaced `each.value` here with `single_header.value` and `single_query_argument.value`, which matches the default iterator symbols for dynamic blocks (which are named after the block type).

Answer (score 0):

Quick update on this in case anyone has a similar issue. Martins answer was great, there was just one thing I had to tweak (might not be an issue on a later version of terraform). In the dynamic content blocks, instead of using `each.value.name`, I used the dynamic block name: `single_header.value.name` and `single_query_argument.value.name`.